# How to do regression analyses with variables from different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, glm

I have two data frames, `tab1` and `tab2`. They look something like these:

```
#tab1
"ID" "grp" "DV" "dat2" ..... "dat"
  1    1   (some data)        NA   
  2    1   (some data)        NA 
  3    1   (some data)        NA 
  4    2   (some data)        NA 
  5    2   (some data)        NA 
  6    2   (some data)        NA 
  7    3   (some data)        NA 
 ....
  6e+7 6e+4(some data)        NA #approx, actual size not shown


#tab2
"grp"  "dat"
  1     123
  2     456
  3     234
 ....
  6e+4  567 #approx, actual size not shown
```

The "dat" column in `tab1` did not exist. My original idea was to copy the values from `tab2` to `tab1` such that `tab1` will look like:

```
#tab1
"ID" "grp" "DV" "dat2" ..... "dat"
  1    1   (some data)        123   
  2    1   (some data)        123 
  3    1   (some data)        123 
  4    2   (some data)        456 
  5    2   (some data)        456 
  6    2   (some data)        456 
  7    3   (some data)        234 
 ....
  6e+7 6e+4(some data)        567 #approx, actual size not shown
```

and then do the regression using `tab1`.
And I did it with the following code, but this turned out to be **very slow** (which does not make sense to me because I expect copying values to an assigned index should be quite fast...):

```
for(i in 1:6e+4) {
  tab1[tab1$grp==i, "dat"] <- tab2[i,2]
  if(i%%100==0) cat(paste("\n", i, "/", 6e+4, sep="")) # progress display
}
```

Then I come to the realization that:

1. I have a lot of columns to copy in this way so this seems inefficient...
2. That will generate an exceptionally large data frame since `tab1` has millions of rows
3. More essentially, maybe I can do the regression using data across different data frames? But I don't know how to do it. (feel like this should be the way out)

Thanks for attending to my problem!

**EDITS:**

A reproducible example:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c93af8fe810a209b5ad54fb1b86d4c4

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but just FYI many regression models assume observations are independent - and if you're final model includes the same "ID" multiple times this probably isn't the case...

Comment: for loops are notoriously slow in R. Without a more concrete example it is hard to see how this could be done.
You could possibly use dplyr::inner_join(tab1,tab2, by = c("ID" = "ID")) or use sqldf("SELECT tab1.*, tab2.dat FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID).
Please, if you can, post a more reproducible example.

Comment: Um... I think I have created some misunderstandings... Sorry for that. I am making some edits to clarify this.

Comment: @HarroCyranka I am preparing an example, thanks.

Comment: @HarroCyranka I have done making the example. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example. My suggestion is the following (using the packages in tidyverse):

```
rm(list = ls()) 
library(tidyverse)

tab1$dat <- NULL #We won't need this column, since we will get it from tab2

tab_1_new <- tab1 %>% dplyr::inner_join(tab2, by = c("grp" = "grp")
```

Comment: Superb! It took less just a few seconds for me to copy a hundred of columns with dplyr. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Thanks Hadley Wickham, though, he is the father of us all :) .

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to assign a column in R, and `for` loop is not the most speedy, so I recommend you to use `data.table` and below you'll see why.

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot) #for nice plot
require(microbenchmark)

foo_loop <- function(){
  for(i in 1:10) {
    tab1[tab1$grp==i,"dat"] <- tab2[i,2]
  }
}

foo_base <- function(){
  tab1$dat = tab2[,2]
}
foo_DT <- function(){
  #fastest solution
  tab1[,dat := tab2$dat]
}


res <- microbenchmark(foo_loop(),foo_base(),foo_DT,times = 1e4)
autoplot(res)
```

[image: result of microbenchmark]

Comment: The syntax here does not work for me: tab1[,dat := tab2$dat].
I guess I need also to specify the columns that I use for matching?